# Please break this regex down for me

Tags: python, regex

The regular expression pattern  `\b([A-Za-z]*(?:s))\b`  matches all words ending in s.

Which part in that expression shows ending? How do I write the beginning of the word is s ? Or ending and beginning is s?

Comment: always try to ask a single question..

Comment: Isn't this regex just a more obfuscated version of `\b([A-Za-z]*s)\b` ?

Comment: We require that questions be useful to other visitors; part of that is writing a problem statement and having a title that articulates that problem statement. Think of your problem statement like this: What would you search on Google if you had this problem?  Whatever that would be would make a good problem statement. Would you search for 'please break down this regex for me'?

Answer (score 2):

If you cared more for visualizations...

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/X8GRfYbOZ9sIQZUQ)

`\b` is a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) character. It is basically covering the space between "words", depending on what engine and flavor of regex you're using.

> Exactly which characters are word characters depends on the regex flavor you're working with. In most flavors, characters that are matched by the short-hand character class `\w` are the characters that are treated as word characters by word boundaries. Java is an exception. Java supports Unicode for `\b` but not for `\w`.

By placing a specific character before the word boundary, it will only ever match words that end with that character; in this case, `s`.  By the defintion as well, it will also match the single character `s`, too.

That said, any word that ends with the letter s will match, and then be captured into the first group, which makes it accessible with `$1` later on.  There is no matching done on the beginning of a word (except to check if it's a word boundary character).

As a hint:  if you want to match if a word starts with a character, then consider placing it after the word boundary character.  For example:

```
\b((?:e)[A-Za-z]*)\b
```

...should match any word that begins with `e`.

Comment: This is beautiful thank you.. I am a visual person so this makes more sense.Any ideas on how to do to b or c? I get beginning and ending now.. but the rest are still a little confusing.

Comment: So here's what I'm going to do.  I'm going to revert your original question back to what it was beforehand, as it's common courtesy to only ask one question per...question.  Since it seems like you've got more questions to ask, feel encouraged to ask them on their own.

Comment: @Makoto I didn't find any regex regarding `How do I write the beginning of the word is s ? Or ending and beginning is s?`

Comment: @AvinashRaj:  It's been broken down pretty decently...If one needs to match if a word starts with s or starts and ends with s, then there's a logical leap to add the character to after the word boundary.  I'll add a small addendum to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`s` before the last `\b` denotes that the string must  ends with a letter `s` . If you want to check also the starting char which must be also an `s`. Then add another `s` after the first word boundary `\b`.

> How do I write the beginning of the word is s ?

```
\bs[A-Za-z]*\b
```

> Or ending and beginning is s?

```
\bs[A-Za-z]*s\b
```

`\b` matches between a word character and a non-word character (*vice-versa*). So `\b` helps to match a complete word. Add anchors if you really mean the start and end of a line.

```
^s[A-Za-z]*s$
```

Comment: okay I get so if I put the s in front that will be the beginning and if I put the s in front and towards the end then it will have both. Thank you sooo much